# How would you substrate a column using tidyverse in R?

Tags: r, tidyverse

So I'm needing to rename a column in R and from that column I need to condense the column. For example in the initial data frame it would say "2017-18" and "2018-19" and I need it to condense to the first four digits, essentially cutting off the "-##" portion. I've attempted to use substr() and when I do it says that I'm having issues with it converting to characters or attempting to convert to a character.

```
data <- read_excel("nba.xlsx")
data1<- data %>%
  rename(year=season) %>%
  select(year)
data1 <- data1 + as.numeric(substr(year,1,4))
```

Above is my code that I currently and have tried rearranging and moving things around. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: If you want to keep first 4 characters in `year` column try `data1$year <- substr(data1$year,1,4)`

Comment: @RonakShah thank you, that worked. Greatly appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

Use `str_replace`:

```
df <- tibble(season = c("2017-18", "2018-19"))

df %>% mutate(year = str_replace(season, "-.*", ""))

# A tibble: 2 x 2
  season  year 
  <chr>   <chr>
1 2017-18 2017 
2 2018-19 2018
```

Alternately, use `str_sub`:

```
str_sub(season, 1, 4)
```